# How can I test the new "Open File" dialog?

Tags: applications, pantheon-files, testing

How can I activate the new open file dialog in files?

http://lmelinux.net/2015/05/05/new-open-file-dialog-coming-to-freya-soon/

As shown below:

[image: Open file dialog screenshot]

Comment: but is it really there?

Comment: @cipricus Yes, the dialog is shipped, but not activated by default due to certain app incompatibilities.

Comment: https://code.launchpad.net/~donadigo/pantheon-files/filechooser-module/+merge/258133 shows right at the top how to use it

Comment: @quassy - ... right at the top...where?

Comment: _"Description of the Change"_ :o

Comment: WOW! The new open file dialog looks cool! Thanks!
Also please give me upvote, thanks

Comment: The Question is about a release or feature that was in testing and is now released, hence the question is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 8):

#### Enable it everywhere

As cipricus said, the dialog is already implemented in the system. If you want to enable it now, you need to have your system *up-to-date* and execute this command in terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings enabled-gtk-modules "['pantheon-filechooser-module']"`

After that, **be sure to reboot your system** and the new dialog should appear.

#### Reset

To disable that if you encounter problems execute and reboot:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings enabled-gtk-modules "[]"`